# copy specific file in command line

Tags: sed, awk

I want to copy specific file done last changes in Oct 16-17,file type is java.

```
shia@ubuntu:~/code$ ls -alxo
total 96
drwx------  2 shia  4096 Oct 20 18:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 61 shia 12288 Oct 20 19:24 ..
-rw-------  1 shia 12288 Oct 16 21:52 .Reuse.java.swp
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   746 Oct 20 11:16 Argus.class
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   302 Oct 20 11:16 Argus.java
-rw-------  1 shia   310 Oct 16 21:30 Call.java
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   417 Oct 17 15:20 Ordinary.class
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   298 Oct 17 14:57 Overriding.java
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   562 Oct 19 21:27 Package.class
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   430 Oct 19 21:27 Package.java
-rw-------  1 shia   729 Oct 17 13:50 Reuse.java
-rw-------  1 shia   424 Oct 17 13:47 Room.java
-rw-------  1 shia   321 Oct 16 21:22 Simpleobject.java
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia  1187 Oct 17 00:04 Static.java
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   686 Oct 17 15:20 Super.class
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia  1010 Oct 17 15:20 Super.java
-rw-------  1 shia   843 Oct 17 14:20 This.java
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   521 Oct 17 14:51 b.java
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia    90 Oct 20 18:54 cp.awk
-rw-rw-r--  1 shia   105 Oct 20 17:19 file.txt
```

I try to specific them but i don't know how to copy them.

```
shia@ubuntu:~/code$ ls -alxo|grep 'Oct 1[67].*java$'|awk '{print $8}'
Call.java
Overriding.java
Reuse.java
Room.java
Simpleobject.java
Static.java
Super.java
This.java
b.java
```

Any help,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.java" -newermt 2012-10-16 ! -newermt 2012-10-18 -exec cp '{}' /home/user/dstFolder/ \;
```

Comment: I want to know how the `find` implementation,Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Also, your method using `ls`, `grep`, `awk` will fail if filenames contain spaces, newlines etc. See the [reasons for not parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I just learn sed and awk in these days.may be it's not the proper approach. I need to learn `find`.

Comment: find is the command to find files. sed is the command for simple text substitutions on a single line within a file. awk is the command for all other text manipulation within a file. You can also use sed or awk for text manipulation in shell strings, but usually you'd just use builtin shell constructs for that. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` to copy the files found:

```
...| xargs -i cp '{}' /home/user/dstFolder/
```

This will copy all the files found to the folder `/home/user/dstFolder/`.

Comment: really helpful command,How fantastic it is!Thanks!I'm new to Linux,and I must to learn more hard and practice more.

Comment: Is there any way i can use awk to obtain this ?

Comment: With coreutils `cp` you can use the target (`-t`) switch to specify destination dir, e.g. `xargs cp -t /home/user/dstFolder/`